# Asp MVC angularjs nested ng-repeat on a view using viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have some code that works.

```
public class testViewModel
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string TestName {get;set;}
  public List<string> SecurityName {get;set;}
}
```

I my view I have the following:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TestName)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecurityName)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="(values, a) in approvalStreams" ng-include="getTemplate(a)"></tr>
    </tbody>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="view">
        <td>{{a.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{a.TestNametd></td>
        <td>

             @*<table>
                 <tbody>
                     <tr ng-repeat="b in values">
                         <td>{{SecurityName}}</td>
                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table>*@


             {{a.SecurityName}}
         </td>   
     </script>
```

What I am trying to do is list the collection of SecurityName's that are in the model.

If, I use {{a.SecurityName}} this renders the first item in the collection, if if I use the table and a nested ng-repeat, the table is rendered as

```
<!-- ngRepeat: b in values -->
```

and not as the required list of names.

Answer (score 0):

Found it was the model. It was only sending back one of the collection not all of them.